# Promise.all with nested map.. First map only work others return empty objects in mongoose

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, mongoose, promise, async-await

Promise.all with nested map.. First map only work others return empty objects in mongoose nodejs iam using only one promise.all to warp both maps

This this code

```
let foundCategory = await Category.findOne({_id: req.params.id})
 let CategoryWithSections =  {...foundCategory.toObject(),sectionsOfCategory: 
      //this map work    
     await Promise.all( foundCategory.sectionsOfCategory.map(async(SOC)=>{
                let sections=  await Section.findOne({_id: SOC.sectionOfCategory })
                return {...sections.toObject(), productsOfSections: 
                 //this map doesn't work 
    sections.productsOfSection.map(async(POS)=>{
                         return await Product.findOne({_id: POS.productOfSection })
                    })
                  }
            // return await sections.filter((section) => section._id === SOC.sectionOfCategory)
        }) )   }
```

Comment: Can you please indent this properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `productsOfSections` object is filled with `sections.productsOfSection.map` which is array of promises. As your are not awaiting it, the promises are not instantly resolved.

The waiting for `await` is always bound to the most inner function it is in. Therefore the `await Product.findOne({_id: POS.productOfSection })` is just bound to the `async(POS)=>{` function, not to the `async(SOC)=>{`.

If you await all the promises in a similar way for the inner `.map` then it will create the "awaiting" chain which will returns you all the values

```
let foundCategory = await Category.findOne({
    _id: req.params.id
})
let CategoryWithSections = {
    ...foundCategory.toObject(),
    sectionsOfCategory:
        //this map work    
        await Promise.all(foundCategory.sectionsOfCategory.map(async (SOC) => {
            let sections = await Section.findOne({
                _id: SOC.sectionOfCategory
            })
            return {
                ...sections.toObject(),
                productsOfSections:
                    //this map doesn't work 
                    await Promise.all(sections.productsOfSection.map(async (POS) => {
                        return await Product.findOne({
                            _id: POS.productOfSection
                        })
                    }))
            }
            // return await sections.filter((section) => section._id === SOC.sectionOfCategory)
        }))
}
```

It is also good to mention that the `async` function just means that the function returns promise and then you are just working with the promises. It means that this part can be written without `await` and even without `async` function, because you are returning promise, therefore the result will be array of promises and thats something that `Promise.all` can work with

```
                await Promise.all(sections.productsOfSection.map((POS) => {
                    return Product.findOne({
                        _id: POS.productOfSection
                    })
                }))
```